# Screen not getting updated

Tags: android

I know that Google engineers are taking some control in regards views layout and redrawing. But I can't understand way changing a view visibility doesn't update the screen. I have a peace of code that is strait forward:

```
if (editMode)
    mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    mView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The "mView" is a TableLayout view that shows its cells when the Activity is in edit mode. And hides it when the Activity is in normal mode. I tried to call "invalidate()" in the "mView" instance and on its parent (that is a FrameLayout), nothing worked. I suspected that could have something to do with the drawing cache so, I disabled it in the parent view (FrameLayout), and in the "mView" instance. I got no changes. Why a View is so stuck like that? What could I possibly doing wrong that the screen doesn't get updated?

Comment: Is the TableLayout empty? If it is, then setting it to invisible won't do anything - it's still there, and still used for layout purposes, just invisible. Have you tried using `View.GONE` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by **screen doesn't get updated** you mean that there is an empty space where the view was once then that is because you made it invisible i.e. we can't see it but it's there. If want to remove that space then use `View.GONE`.

Comment: Hi, Kandwal. Thanks for help.
I already tried `View.GONE` and it had the same effect. The TableLayout is not there, as I checked the `getVisibility()` method. But the screen is not updated and the grid (slots) are still shown.

By the way, I already try calling `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` in the FrameLayout (parent of TableLayout) and in the proper TableLayout just to be sure. Waste of time.

Comment: Since you are mentioning your real problem now which may be different from what you asked, I would suggest you to ask a new question with code of your layout and activity and possibly a snapshot. This way you will get maximum help as very few now will give you an answer. If you accept my suggestion then remove update from your question and accept this answer.

Comment: Hi, Kandwal. Thanks for your advice. I accept your answer and remove the update. But I will not ask another question right now. This problem has more than a week without solution and my superiors delayed the launch of the application. Some time in the near future I will ask the new question and follow your advice.
Thanks again.

Comment: @user3191893 Surely, ask your question anytime we are here.. :D